# Find averaged array of fixed size from a changing size original array

Tags: arrays, matlab, grouping, average

I have arrays with different size that need to be averaged (with the neighbours) in order to give a fixed array size as a result.

For example:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
b=[7,8,9,10];
c=[11,12,13];

n=3; %length of the resulting array

ave_a=[1.5, 3.5, 5.5] (non overlapping window [2]);
ave_b=[7.5,8.5,9.5] (overlapping window [2]);
ave_c=[11,12,13];
```

The average method is not important here.
Is there any solution to this problem?

Thansk for the help.

Comment: If I understood correctly the first thing to clear up would be to choose which solution you want. Because, as the gap between the array size and `n` grows the number of solutions increases. For example you computed `ave_a` with non-overlapping windows of size 2. But it could also be computed with overlapping windows of size 4 with an overlap of 3. IMO you should decide either on looking for the solution with no (or the smallest) overlap or for the solution with the biggest window and overlap. Or have a scheme that return every solution. What makes more sense for your application?

Comment: please follow the question guidelines, what did you do to solve the problem?

Comment: The problem is based on averaging heart rate data coming from a PPG signal. From the elaboration of the data as well the nature of the device that as a finite data loss I will have data about the heart rate taken from a 5 minutes acquisition but with not known a priori length of the array. Sometimes I will end with 20 HR records, sometimes 26.  I have to extract 5 averaged samples from the array, one estimation for every minute.  The best method to average the heart rate it will be an overlapping window with a large size. Thanks for your help